# Arrayformula breaks when sorting its own column (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

So I have this formula.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(J1='Box CP (EdenXS)'!B1,IF(MainNamesEdenXS=DataNamesEdenXS,Week1)`

Which breaks when I sort its column to see which value is maximum/minimum, I assume because it is dependent on the `MainNamesEdenXS` range.

I also know of this formula.

`=IF(A3='Base Character Sheet'!A3,'Base Character Sheet'!B3,IF(A3='Base Character Sheet'!A4,'Base Character Sheet'!B4)`

Which doesn't break but ends up being an extensive time waster.

So I was wondering if there is a way to either make it so the array formula doesn't break or shorten the If statement so that I don't sit for 30 minutes writing out 1 nested if statement.

Comment: Try to look at the `SWITCH` function to replace the nested `IF`. My guess for the other one is that you have the formula in one cell, and that effectively writes out the array. Then when you try to sort it you move the formula so it becomes a mess. Try using `SORT` to sort the array as you want.

Comment: This looks like a basic `VLOOKUP` formula to me.

Comment: Can you please share your sheet?